# Amazon Selling Partner API - QuotaExceeded error

Tags: python, rate-limiting, amazon-selling-partner-api

I am trying to create a report of type GET_FBA_FULFILLMENT_CUSTOMER_SHIPMENT_SALES_DATA through the Selling Partner API.
I request to create the report 18 times in a row, and starting from the 16th time I get the following error:
[{'code': 'QuotaExceeded', 'message': 'You exceeded your quota for the requested resource.', 'details': ''}]

It is important for me to note that I wait between one request and another according to the rate limit defined in the documentation.
There are probably additional limitations that I am not aware of and I have not found official information about them, such as a limitation of retrieving a certain report per day or month.
Does anyone have any information that can help?

I write Python code and use the python-amazon-sp-api library. (I don't think it matters)

Thank you!